# cast JavaScriptObject to gwt widget

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, uibinder

may i know how to cast JavascriptObject get from JSNI into gwt as gwt CUstomWidget

`CustomWiget widget = (CustomWidget) javascriptObjectFromJSNI;`  //doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CustomWidget as the return type of your JSNI method. The example at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html#example-json does this with Customer (which extends JavaScriptObject):

```
private native Customer getFirstCustomer() /*-{
  return $wnd.jsonData[0];
}-*/;
```

If your CustomWidget is really a Widget (not a JavaScriptObject), then you're probably looking for somthing quite different: In that case you'd have to write a `wrap()` method like `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button.wrap()`.

Comment: CustomWidget is gwt custom widget, not json.  can you elaborate more on wrap() ?

Comment: @cometta: Well, you'd use something like `com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.getElementById(String)` or some other method to retrieve a com.google.gwt.user.client.Element, and then feed it into your own wrap() method, which you'd have to write in the style of Button.wrap(), Anchor.wrap(), Label.wrap(), ...

Comment: I looked through Label source code. and I do similar and able to get the element. but after i done new CustomWidget(Element), and trying to get the value user entered, it's null. is it possible to get user entered value through wrap() method to return customwidget?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706271/gwt-custom-widget-wrap-method

Answer (score 4):

You cannot cast an ELement to a Widget. You can use GQuery to help you out in this case.

GQuery.$(element).widget() will give you the GWT widget you are looking for on your DOM.

Comment: Hi Karthik, while using GQuery error is coming like No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery; did you forget to inherit a required module?...What can I do now...