# gwt custom widget wrap method

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

my custom widget look like below

```
public class CustomWidget extends Composite {

    public static CustomWidget wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element element) {

        assert Document.get().getBody().isOrHasChild(element);

        CustomWidget customWiget = new CustomWidget(element);//this line is still ok,customWidget has value

       customWiget.onAttach();//i get Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
       RootPanel.detachOnWindowClose(customWiget);


        return button;
      }


protected CustomWidget(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element element) {
        setElement(element);


}

}
```

is my wrap method correctly written? I get error at the point i commented

```
Element element = DOM.getElementById( object );
CustomWidget testKeyValue= CustomWidget.wrap(element);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that `element != null` after this line:

```
Element element = DOM.getElementById( object );
```

(Probably assertions are [turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/assertion-in-java), so your current code will only fail in onAttach().)